# Build a JSON object using elements from an arraylist along with their corresponding values from a map

Tags: java, json, dictionary, gson

I need to create  a JSON object as it was deserialized from a map, but using a `Arraylist<Integer>` instead of the list as keys and values. What is the best way to create such a JSON using Gson library?

I could only think of first creating a new `HashMap` from the `ArrayList` elements  and then convert that it to JSON. Not sure if there is a better way than this, avoiding creation of new map.

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you find any obstacles after reading the doc?

Comment: can you show your expected output and input

Comment: I don't know if you can skip the manual creation of the Hashmap. Considering that, given the very nature of the ArrayList structure, the keys would be arbitrary, I don't think you can avoid going through the list yourself to transform it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the creation of the map, you can use "low level" Gson objects. This is how you can do it:

```
public class Q20049678 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      al.add(1);
      al.add(1);
      al.add(2);
      al.add(3);
      al.add(5);
      al.add(8);

      JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
      for (Integer i : al) {
         jo.add(String.valueOf(i), new JsonPrimitive(i));
      }

      System.out.println(jo.toString());

   }

}
```

This is the result that I formatted with an external tool.

```
{
  "1":1,
  "2":2,
  "3":3,
  "5":5,
  "8":8
}
```